# PHP mail shows BCC address in the email

Tags: php, gmail

My application sends emails to an Admin and to Customers upon payment is received. 
I would like to add a BCC field for a backup email and do not want it to show. 
I tried adding it as a BCC field but it is still showing when the email is received. The header reads as follows:

to me, bcc: the BCC e-mail, bcc: second BCC email

My code is as follows:

```
$to="email@hotmail.com";
$subject= "New order";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <email@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC:".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "BCC: email@hotmail.com, email2@hotmail.com".PHP_EOL;

mail($to, $subject, $msg2, $headers);
mail($email, 'Payment Confirmation', $msg2customer, $headers);
```

I tried removing the CC field, still the same result.

*Note: When the emails are received by a @hotmail.com account the BCC are hidden, but when received by a @Gmail.com account the BCC are shown. I'm on local host, did not try on a live server.
Thank you

Comment: not sure if it will solve the problem, but according to the specs its `Bcc` not `BCC` and should end with `"\r\n"` not `PHP_EOL` all the headers should end this way

Comment: @IdontDownVote Tried, same result. Thanks for your suggestion. By the way I read on another post that PHP_EOL is better for global configuration of servers.

Comment: PHP_EOL is fine for real world line breaks, but the mail headers have a defined format regardless of server type. Personally i never use mail() its very underpowered, consider phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: @IdontDownVote Sure, thank you. What do you think if I just use another call of mail() and put the BCC there instead? Will that slow things too much?

Comment: The BCC header shows up because you put it there. Don't do that. BCC is not a feature of SMTP, it's a feature of mail clients that send messages to destinations not listed in the headers. Hell, headers are pretty much entirely optional and/or for the benefit of mail client programs, so long as the intermediate MXes aren't too picky. Using the `mail()` function essentially make *you* the client program, so you're going to have to implement proper BCC functionality yourself.

Comment: And don't use blank headers like that CC you've got there. It's malformed and picky MXes will increase your spam rating for stuff like that.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for your input. Weird thing is it's working in Hotmail, but only Gmail shows the bcc field. Also  if you have a relevant resource about how to go about implementing bcc functionality that would be great. Thank you again.

Comment: @MarwanAlkhalil for every person that should recieve a copy of the email you should call `mail()`. But you should also never be in the position to call `mail()` directly because there are a LOT of considerations beyond this that you'd need to address. Use a more robust mailing library like PHPmailer that addresses those considerations for you.

Comment: @Sammitch Yeah I currently do not need too much done, therefore I wouldn't wanna import an extension library. I currently only need to send 4 e-mails 2 of which should not appear to the normal user (just for backup and testing). Currently I am calling `mail()` 4 times, however I am not sure if that stresses the server a lot more than doing it in a more sophisticated way or doesn't matter much. I appreciate your input!